# Tracking nonlinear real arithmetic assertions using implications versus the :named mechanism gives different answers

Tags: z3

While trying to solve large nonlinear real arithmetic problems, I track every assertion using answer literals and explicit implications, as recommended in other posts. It should be equivalent to using the (! (...) :named p1) syntax of the SMT2 format. It seems, though, that both methods are handled differently internally.

The following SMT2 code gives an UNKNOWN result, with explanation "(incomplete (theory arithmetic))":

```
(set-option :print-success false) 
(set-option :produce-unsat-cores true) ; enable generation of unsat cores
(set-option :produce-models true) ; enable model generation

(declare-const p1 Bool)
(declare-const p2 Bool)
(declare-const p3 Bool)
(declare-const p4 Bool)
(declare-const p5 Bool)

(declare-const x1 Real)
(declare-const x2 Real)
(declare-const x3 Real)

(assert (=> p1 (= x1 (/ 1.0 (* x2 x2)))))
(assert (=> p2 (not (= x2 0.0))))
(assert (=> p3 (= x3 (* 2.0 x1))))
(assert (=> p4 (= x3 5.0)))
(assert (=> p5 (< x3 0.0)))
(check-sat p1 p2 p3)
(get-info:reason-unknown)
```

On the other hand, the following SMT2 code gives the correct answer, UNSAT, and produces an informative unsat core (p4, p5):

```
(set-option :print-success false) 
(set-option :produce-unsat-cores true) ; enable generation of unsat cores
(set-option :produce-models true) ; enable model generation

(declare-const x1 Real)
(declare-const x2 Real)
(declare-const x3 Real)

(assert (! (= x1 (/ 1.0 (* x2 x2))) :named p1))
(assert (! (not (= x2 0.0)) :named p2))
(assert (! (= x3 (* 2.0 x1)) :named p3))
(assert (! (= x3 5.0) :named p4))
(assert (! (< x3 0) :named p5))
(check-sat)
(get-unsat-core)
;(get-model)
```

My specific questions are:

- How can this differing behavior be explained? What is recommended practice for tracking nonlinear real equations and inequalities?
- What would be the equivalent OCaml API call for the (! (...) :named p1) syntax of SMT2? Is it assert_and_track?

I am using Z3 version 4.3.2 from the ml-ng branch under Linux.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new ML API has been integrated into the unstable branch a couple months ago, and the ml-ng branch has been removed. A few bugfixes/extensions were added to it's worth updating.

assert_and_track does exactly what you suspect and it is internally translated to the first example given.

The difference in behavior is explained by `(check-sat p1 p2 p3)` which is missing p4 and p5. Once those are added, the two versions behave exactly the same and they produce the same unsat core.

Comment: Thank you, indeed adding p4 and p5 fixes that problem. However, playing with the example brought up another problem that I'm posting in a new question.

Comment: The new question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29277650/solvability-of-nonlinear-real-arithmetic-with-premises)